# sql server - How can I put the values in a result side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #E (
ID INT ,
NAME VARCHAR(20),
RESULT VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #E VALUES (1,'DOMAIN','marka')
INSERT INTO #E VALUES (1,'EXTENSION','.com')
INSERT INTO #E VALUES (1,'TYPE','WEB')

SELECT * FROM #E

Declare @DomainName varchar(20) = ''
--How can I put the values(RESULT) in a result side by side
SELECT RESULT FROM #E  WHERE ID=1 AND NAME IN ('DOMAIN','EXTENSION')
```

How can I put the values(RESULT) in a result side by side
   How can I do it? --> Set @DomainName = 'marka.com'

@DomainName = 'marka.com'  --How do I add

[image]

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Are you asking how to assign the value of a variable in a `SELECT` statement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#setting-a-value-in-a-transact-sql-variable

Comment: Thank you to everyone. i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DomainName varchar(20) = ''

SELECT @DomainName = (DOMAIN + EXTENSION) FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM #E  
    WHERE ID=1 
    AND NAME IN ('DOMAIN','EXTENSION')
) as main
PIVOT
(
    MAX(RESULT)
    FOR NAME IN ([DOMAIN],[EXTENSION])
) piv

SELECT @DomainName
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for conditional aggregation?

```
select max(case when name = 'DOMAIN' then result end) as domain,
       max(case when name = 'EXTENSION' then result end) as extension,
       max(case when name = 'TYPE' then result end) as type
from #E e
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH res1
AS (
    SELECT result
        ,ID
    FROM #E
    WHERE name = 'DOMAIN'
    )
    ,res2
AS (
    SELECT result
        ,ID
    FROM #E
    WHERE name = 'EXTENSION'
    )
SELECT CONCAT (
        res1.result
        ,res2.result
        )
FROM RES1
INNER JOIN RES2 ON RES1.ID = RES2.ID
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2c98/9)

Comment: Yes, This is the result I want. But So how do I set it @DomainName